# Kendo UI Grid resize column event triggers also rezise kendoWindow event

Tags: kendo-ui, resize, kendo-grid, window-resize

I have a grid inside a popup window.
Using the new kendo release, 2014.2.718, the resize column event of the grid also triggers the popup window resize event. What could be the problem here?

Link JSbin: 
http://jsbin.com/bageveta/4/edit

Comment: You have created an loop on resize event, column resizes grid, grid resizes window which in turn resizes the Grid again which resizes the Window that is the reason for this particular behavior. Either you need to put a fixed size on the Grid or a flag when the Grid is resized then not to resize the Window or similar limitation.

Comment: grid shouldn't resize window. Here, same behavior without custom resize event on window: http://jsbin.com/bageveta/7/edit

Comment: Moreover, without any custom resize events.. just kendo default behavior. http://jsbin.com/bageveta/8/edit

Comment: I take it back, it seems you are correct and have found a bug.

Comment: The problem does not appear with version 2014.1.528, so is definitely a version issue. See:  
http://jsbin.com/bageveta/11/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to have been resolved in the latest Kendo UI starting with version 2014.2.903.